# HighCharts. Change options dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I set tooltip option `enabled = FALSE`.

I want change it to `TRUE` when user clicks on point.

How can I do it?

```
series : [{
            data : data,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    enabledTooltip();
                }
            }
        }],
//.......................        
var enabledTooltip = function(){
 // what I should write here?
};
```

Comment: can u put full code of highcharts function?

Comment: It's not supported dynamically - but solution with recreating chart will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's fairly easy.

```
var enabledTooltip = function () {
    var options = chart.options;
    options.tooltip.enabled = true;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eNMvw/50/

Answer (score 0):

```
var enabledTooltip = function(){
    a.series[0]["dataGrouping"]["enabled"] = true;
};
var a = {series : [{
            data : "data",
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    enabledTooltip();
                }
            }
        }]};

(function test(){
    console.log("before click: "+a.series[0]["dataGrouping"]["enabled"]);//before click: false 
    enabledTooltip();
    console.log("after click: "+a.series[0]["dataGrouping"]["enabled"]);//after click: true 
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you check below code:

It's works for me.

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                   click: function(e) {
                        enabledTooltip();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: [{
                dashStyle: "Solid"
            }, false],
             enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });



    var enabledTooltip = function(){
alert(567);
        var options = chart.options;
        options.tooltip.enabled = true;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};

});
```

Hope this works for you