# Dynamically change center of a Highchart pie?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to change the center of a Highchart pie on a window resize event but I cannot achieve to do it.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frntz/su8ts5zo/)

where I'm trying to move the pie without success ...

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                center: ["50%","50%"]
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2
            }]
        }]
    });
    $('#changeposition').click(function() {
       chart.options.plotOptions.pie.center = ["0","50%"];
        console.log(chart);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<button id="changeposition" type="button">To the left</button>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this:

```
$('#changeposition').click(function() {
        chart.options.plotOptions.pie.center = ["0%","50%"];
        console.log(chart);
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart.options);
});
```

You needed to redraw the chart.

Here is a forked jsfiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/45j7bxnn/1/

Comment: is there a way to slide the pie instead of recreate it ?

Comment: I would recomend to move the container div, there you could animate it as you want or even using some sort of library like greensock.

Comment: You cannot modify charts center dynamically, you will have to redraw it.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here at [HighCharts. Change options dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402223/highcharts-change-options-dynamically)

```
chart.options.plotOptions.pie.center = ["0%","50%"];
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart.options);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/su8ts5zo/2/

Comment: is there a way to slide the pie instead of recreate it ?